# Aggregate multiple columns based on single group by in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains data in attached image format 
[image]

Or sample data

```
transactionDate         |   AllocatedHrs | ActivityName                     
2014-10-10 10:43:55.763,1.5830000000000000,abc
2014-10-10 10:13:55.763,1.2830000000000000,def
2014-10-10 11:33:55.763,0.2830000000000000,ghi
2014-10-10 11:53:55.763,0.7170000000000000,ijk
```

I need to group the data for this table based on transactionDate , the data of AllocatedHrs should get added and third column should add the names of grouped tables i.e

```
network                        | Sum                    |Date
abcdef2014-10-10 10:43:55.763, 2.8660000000000000, 2014-10-10 10:43:55.763
ghiijk2014-10-10 11:33:55.763,   1.0,              2014-10-10 11:33:55.763
```

I am using the following query

```
with A as 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, transactionDate), 0) as testDate, 
   activityId , AllocatedHrs ,activity_name
  from test_group 
  group by activityId ,transactionDate,AllocatedHrs,activity_name
  )
  select  cast(a.activity_name as VARCHAR) +  cast(a.testDate as VARCHAR) as network
  ,sum(A.AllocatedHrs)as allc 
  ,a.activityId as activity
  from A
  group by a.testDate
  order by a.activityId
```

But whenever i am trying to run the same i am getting the following error

`Column 'A.activity_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: fields that are not in the group by clause must have an aggregate function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: add cast(a.activity_name as VARCHAR) to your group by clause or surround it with an aggregate function MAX(cast(a.activity_name as VARCHAR))

Comment: Adding cast(a.activity_name as VARCHAR) will run the query successfully , but it does not solve the problem i.e i need to group the data based on trasactiondate and concat the names of groupings into a new column

Comment: i.e                                               `transactionDate         |   AllocatedHrs | ActivityName                     
2014-10-10 10:43:55.763,1.5830000000000000,abc
2014-10-10 10:13:55.763,1.2830000000000000,def `              should be aggregated as                                                    `network                        | Sum                    |Date
abcdef2014-10-10 10:43:55.763, 2.8660000000000000, 2014-10-10 10:43:55.763`.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
  (
     transactionDate DATETIME,
     AllocatedHrs    NUMERIC(22, 10),
     ActivityName    VARCHAR(200)
  )

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES      ('2014-10-10 10:00:00.000',1.5830000000000000,'abc'),
            ('2014-10-10 10:00:00.000',1.2830000000000000,'def'),
            ('2014-10-10 11:00:00.000',0.2830000000000000,'ghi'),
            ('2014-10-10 11:00:00.000',0.7170000000000000,'ijk')

SELECT t1.transactionDate,
       Sum(AllocatedHrs),
       (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, ActivityName)
        FROM   @table1 b
        WHERE  b.transactionDate = t1.transactionDate
        ORDER  BY ActivityName
        FOR XML PATH(''))
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR, t1.transactionDate, 111 )
FROM   @table1 t1
GROUP  BY t1.transactionDate
```

Comment: You can also use an ORDER BY in the correlated subquery that is concatenated the values together to ensure the network names are in alphabetical order. Depending on your real data you may also need to introduce a GROUP BY / DISTINCT. There are lots of articles that discuss the FOR XML PATH concatenation technique.